# How to disable autologin in a website - (Android Studio)

Tags: java, post, get, jsoup, autologin

i'm writing an app but i've a problem, I make the GET and POST request with Jsoup to do the login in the Iliad website, when I run the app, it log in also with wrong credentials, I think it is because the website do the autologin, but i've no idea how to remove it.

This is the code:

```
try {
                    res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.iliad.it/account/")
                            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                            //.cookie("auth_mobile", "0")
                            .execute();
                    SESSID = res.cookie("ACCOUNT_SESSID");
                    //AUTH = res.cookie("auth_mobile");

                    response = Jsoup.connect("https://www.iliad.it/account/")
                            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                            .data("login-ident", MainActivity.id)
                            .data("login-pwd", MainActivity.pwd)
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101   Firefox/45.0")
                            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                            .followRedirects(true)
                            .cookie("ACCOUNT_SESSID", SESSID)
                            //.cookie("auth_mobile", "0")
                            .execute();

                    Errore = false;
                    doc = Jsoup.parse(response.parse().outerHtml());
                    System.out.println(doc);

                } catch (Exception e) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the session cookie from the headers on the initial GET request:

```
set-cookie: ACCOUNT_SESSID=9p3lg...1j2e3; path=/account/; HttpOnly
```

In any subsequent requests to the server you must set this as:

```
Cookie: ACCOUNT_SESSID=9p3lg...1j2e3
```

So you should have something more like:

```java
 response = Jsoup.connect("https://www.iliad.it/account/")
                 .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                 .data("login-ident", MainActivity.id)
                 .data("login-pwd", MainActivity.pwd)
...
                 .cookie("Cookie", "ACCOUNT_SESSID=" + SESSID) // <<<
               //.cookie("auth_mobile", "0")
                 .execute();
```

This should get you a step closer.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a beginner, I don't know what do you mean, what I have to write on my code?

Comment: The cookie is the browsers/servers way of tracking a user-session. You need to set this in the HTTP headers (correctly) otherwise it wont work how you want